# Get list of submitted fees along with date from fees table using student_id as foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a  *students* table and *fees* table.

**students**

```
--------------
|id | name |
--------------
```

**fees**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| id| student_id | paid_fees | created_at | updated_at | 
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Here, `student_id` from fees is `foreign key` that references to `id` on `students.`

I have two models for these tables, and I have defined a `hasMany` relationship between them. 
Because ,**A student can submit the total fees in parts, So he can have more than one record in `fees` table**

**Student.php**

```
lass Student extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'roll_no', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    public function fees(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\StudentFees');
    }

}
```

**Fee.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Fees extends Model
{
    public function student(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
    }
}
```

I tried to get all the occurenece of the records related to the srudent_id.
`$student->fees->where('student_id', $student - >id)`
It gives me an arrays of the records as a object. Please suggest if there is a better way.

I am trying to get `paid_fee` record which is  related to a student_id with `created_at` or `updated_at` record too.

Maybe like this: [ [2500, '2019-05-19], [3500, '2019-06-28'] ]

So **I am  trying to get a list of all submitted fees along with date related to student_id.**

Comment: *"I am trying to get a list of all submitted fees along with date related to student_id"*, would you be so kind to show what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tarasovynch I updated the question, that's what I have tried so far. If there is any better way I will be grateful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your `StudentFees` object you can access the `Student` with just `$studentFee->student`.

But if you need absolutely that kind of output, you can write something like

```
$studentFees = StudentFees::all();
if ($studentFees) {
    $output = $studentFees->map(function($fee) {
        return [ $fee->paid_fees, $fee->student->created_at ];
    });   
    // do whatever you want with $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my thinking, you created your file `Fee.php` and your class model is `StudentFees`. it seems to be not match.i think you should rename that file is `StudentFees.php`.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried to make it simple That's why I posted it as Fees, but I forgot to change the class. I changed it, thanks. By the way It should be a comment as well.